# How to insert a letter inside numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create an empty matrix and then insert letters inside.

```
s = np.zeros(2,3)
s[0,0]='A'
```

Output:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'A'
```

From my understanding matrix `s` only accepts numbers, so it rejects the string `A`. But is it possible to do it without complicated functions?

Comment: You defined `s` as `np.zeros(2,3)`; the default `dtype` of `zeros` is `numpy.float64` as per the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) which you should have read before posting here. You can't convert the letter `A` to a `numpy.float64`. If you want to be able to store any object type, you'd have to specify the `dtype` of the `ndarray` as `object`. So, `s=np.zeros((2,3), dtype=object)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done, just specify `dtype=object`:

```
s = np.zeros((2,3), dtype=object)
s[0,0]='A'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some options, this depends on your use case so I explained 2 of those:

---

### Just want an array of a type specifically

from the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html), you should have read that you can specify `dtype` as a parameter in the [`np.zeros`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) function; your type should be specified in the `dtype` parameter:

```
>>> zeros = np.zeros((2,3),dtype=str)
>>> zeros
array([['', '', ''],
       ['', '', '']], dtype='<U1')
>>> zeros[0,0] = 'A'
>>> zeros
array([['A', '', ''],
       ['', '', '']], dtype='<U1')
```

---

### Just want a general option for all types?

Use `dtype=object` as it's in use for general types.

###### Example

```
>>> zeros = np.zeros((2,3),dtype=object)
>>> zeros
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]], dtype=object)
>>> zeros[0,0] = "A"
>>> zeros
array([['A', 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]], dtype=object)
```

Some info from the docs:

> The 24 built-in array scalar type objects all convert to an associated data-type object. This is true for their sub-classes as well.

> Note that not all data-type information can be supplied with a type-object: for example, flexible data-types have a default itemsize of 0, and require an explicitly given size to be useful.

Useful links:

- [official docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#index-2)
- [user manual dtypes](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html)
- [geeksforgeek dtypes in Numpy](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-type-object-dtype-numpy-python/)
- [W3School NumPy Data Types](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_data_types.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy arrays to store strings is not something that one would agree with. Or even do.

But if you really want and you think it is useful you can try this:

```
#writing full code btw:
s = numpy.array(0)
s = numpy.zeros(2, dtype=int)
s = numpy.array(list(map(list, "A")))
print(s)
```